# Domain Driven Design workflow how to do it right?

Tags: domain-driven-design

For example I have workflow set value. What if value already set? I have several options what to do.

1. In the same workflow overwrite value.
2. Reject and start new workflow to overwrite value
3. Reject and start new workflow to unset value and after start new workflow to set value in new cell

I dont know how to do it by right way
I will be grateful for your help
Sorry for my english, it's not my first language

UPD:
Concept of workflow I get from book Domain Modeling Made Functional by Scott Wlaschin. Definition workflow from book  - A Workflow is a detailed description of part of a business process. That is, it lists the exact steps that an employee (or software component) needs to do to accomplish a business goal or sub-goal. We’ll limit a "workflow" to what a single person or team can do, so that when a business process is spread over multiple teams (as the ordering process is), we’ll divide the overall business process into a series of smaller workflows, which are then coordinated in some way.

Value and cell its just termins from database

For example, I have a client and he has an appointment at 12:00. I receive a request to make an appointment for a client for another time. I have several options what to do.

1. In the same workflow overwrite time.
2. Reject and start new workflow to overwrite time
3. Reject and start new workflow to unset now time and after set new time

In this case what the right way to do it ?

Comment: Hello! Can you please add some more info regarding your use case? I find hard to understand what "workflow" and "value" means, they are very generic concepts. Also in point 3 you refer to a "cell" what is a "cell" in your use case?

Comment: Hey! I have updated the question with more information.